# How to scope an object instance to Jetpack Compose navigation graph lifecycle using Hilt?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

Let's assume I have a multimodule Jetpack Compose project with feature modules and I want to scope some object instances to features lifecycles. For example, I want to scope `AuthRepo` instance to `AuthFeature` lifecycle and delete it from memory right after user logged in. Let's also assume that my feature consists of a few composable screens.

So, my `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ...
            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = *AuthFeature graph*) {
               navigation(*AuthFeature graph*) {
                   composable(*First Screen*) { backStackEntry ->
                       val authGraphEntry = *get authGraphEntry*
                       val vm = hiltViewModel<AuthViewModel>(authGraphEntry)
                       ...
                   }

                   composable(*Second Screen*) { backStackEntry ->
                       val authGraphEntry = *get authGraphEntry*
                       val vm = hiltViewModel<AuthViewModel>(authGraphEntry)
                       ...
                   }
              }

              *Other feature graph with multiple screens*
              
         }
    }
```

In such case there's no problem: `AuthViewModel`, which is common for both screens, is scoped to `AuthFeature` graph and I can use Hilt's `@ViewModelScoped` annotation while injecting `AuthRepo`. So `AuthViewModel` will be destroyed after navigating to the other feature (with popping up to the root) and `AuthRepo` is going to be destroyed too.

The problem appears when I decide to create one ViewModel per screen. The first screen and the second screen consider to use the same instance of `AuthRepo`, however annotating `AuthRepo` with `@ViewModelScoped` leads to creating two instances of `AuthRepo` as I have 2 ViewModels. Annotating it with `@Singleton` leads to creating one single instance for the whole app, which is not going to be removed after navigating to another feature.

I came up with 2 ways to solve the issue:

1. Wrap every feature in an activity and use `@ActivityRetainedScoped`. However I want to use SingleActivity pattern in my project so this solution is not valid for me.
2. Use Dagger and its custom scopes. But I'd like to have a simpler solution without manual component lifecycle handling to keep code cleaner and less error-prone.

On the other hand, I don't want to leave 1 ViewModel per feature because one day it can grow to an enormous amount lines of code. Any ideas? Please correct me if I'm wrong in some of my statements.